# PHP Only print to table if is not specified value

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I have some code where I am populating a table using data from a database query and a for-each loop. I have a status column, which can be one of four values - Processed, rejected, requested or cancelled.

What I need to find out is how I can make the table not include a value if it is set to processed? (`$stat[Status]]`)

Any advice on what I should use to get this working would be much appreciated.

```
print "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped datatable' style='font-size:0.7em;'>";
print "<thead>";
    print "<tr>";
        print "<th>ID</th>";
        print "<th>Status</th>";
        print "<th>Title</th>";
        print "<th>First Name</th>";
        print "<th>Last Name</th>";
        print "<th>Position</th>";
    print "</tr>";
print "</thead>";
print "<tbody>";

foreach($data as $stat)

{
    print "<tr>";
        print "<td>$stat[ID]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[Status]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[Title]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[FirstName]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[LastName]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[Position]</td>";            
    print "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You can use `if($stat[Status] != 'Processed')` statement for status inside your loop. Are you looking for something else ?

Comment: You should only get the information you need from the database when you make your query.

Comment: Why don't you add the condition in your database query? That will be faster efficient

Comment: @jeroen So are you saying that I should specify to display everything but processed in the query, rather than getting php to handle it?

Comment: Yes, add a `WHERE` condition in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($data as $stat)
{
    if ($stat[Status] === "processed") {
        continue;
    }

    print "<tr>";
    ....
}
```

This way you skip all 'processed' rows.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($data as $stat)
{
    if($stat[Status]!= "processed") {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>$stat[ID]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[Status]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[Title]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[FirstName]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[LastName]</td>";
        print "<td>$stat[Position]</td>";            
        print "</tr>";
    }

}
```